# StackOverflowError on Android when using ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, android, error-handling, stack-overflow

I am working on an Android project, and I am trying to save a Trie to a file using objectOutputStream and then be able to read it back in. For some reason tho I keep getting the StackOverFlowError, and it is happening even when my Trie has 3 words in it.

Try code: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/52trie/TST.java.html

This is my read/write code

```
public static void writeObject(Context c, String key, Object object)
{
    try{
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = c.openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
        objectOutputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {}


}

public static Object readObject(Context c, String key)
{
    Object object = null;
    try{
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = c.openFileInput(key);
        try{
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        try{
        object = objectInputStream.readObject();}
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
        ;} catch (IOException e) {}

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return object;
}
```

and this is the error I am getting. There should be no way a 3 word Trie can cause a stackoverflow error.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at java.lang.Thread.currentThread(Thread.java:476)
            at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:53)
            at dalvik.system.BlockGuard.getThreadPolicy(BlockGuard.java:140)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:148)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:422)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:179)
            at libcore.io.Streams.readSingleByte(Streams.java:41)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:175)
            at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:96)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.nextTC(ObjectInputStream.java:506)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:680)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
            at java
```

Comment: Could you show us your `Trie` class? Does it contain a circular reference?

Comment: Sure its http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/52trie/TST.java.html

Comment: I *think* the problem is in your tree structure. You should check whether your tree contains cycles and whether any `Node` contains a reference to itself.

Comment: Even if it did. Can it really cause a problem for 3 words? I understand when it contains a ton of words.

Comment: If it contains a cycle, then the serialization will get stuck in a loop: Node1 > Node2 > Node 3 > Node 1 > Node 2 etc. If there is a circular reference, the amount of nodes doesn't matter; it'll just get stuck as soon as it reaches the cycle.

Comment: I don't think it can have a cycle in it. Because I can insert words, and find words without a problem. I think if I had a cycle it would crash at some point. I only encounter this issue when I try to write to a file

Comment: The difference is that for insertion/retrieval, you only need to *find* a certain node, while serialization needs to *store* it. A `Node` contains references to it's children, so they need to be serialized as well. If one of those children is an ancestor or the parent of the current node, then the process will eventually end up at the same node, thus looping infinitely and overflowing the stack.

Comment: @DennisW No. He doesn't need to check for cycles. Serialization can handle those, but he may need to serialize it manually in a non-recursive way.